# Removing a "backports" PPA

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde

Hoping to fix a few issues with KDE apps on Kubuntu 16.04, I added a backports PPA (`kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-xenial`), and updated manually a couple of apps (apt-get install  --only-upgrade`).

- made very extensive changes to the system (many packages added/removed)
- created more problems than it solved (my fault?)

Furthermore it is about time I apply a bunch of regular upgrades, and I'm not confident enough to allow a general upgrade from the PPA.

So

1. how can I remove the PPA with minimal damage? (What happens to the already installed software?)
2. Is there any chance that the problems come from either not upgrading my system before adding the PPA (no upgrades in the last two months) or because I used the wrong option to upgrade?

Comment: The title should be **"How to remove the backports PPA and go back to fully stable / LTS?"**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a safe alternative to manually removing PPA's, you can install a tool called `ppa-purge`

You can install this by running:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

And then to remove the `ppa`, you can simply run:

```
ppa-purge ppa:ppa_name_here
```

#### What does this tool actually do?

Instead of doing something like

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ppa_name_here
```

`ppa_purge` is a safe alternative because it gracefully downgrades whatever was installed from the mentioned...

And to answer your question, assuming that the "already installed software" was installed through the `ppa`... It will be most likely be gracefully removed...

And as to your second question, one may never know what errors may or may not arise from these specific situations...

Comment: OK, will try that

Comment: Worked perfectly. Actually a life-saver because the plasma shell started crashing at logon. Removing the ppa and going back seems to a fixed most issues. Many thanks.

Comment: Excellent solution, just tested in 22.04 Kubuntu LTS. The main part is that it not only removes a PPA but also its updates, so that it rolls back, downgrades, re-installs the LTS (or whatever initial) versions of the software packages modified /upgraded because of the PPA.