# type password on Kubuntu lock-screen withour using mouse

Tags: kubuntu, lock-screen

When Kubuntu (20.04) is locked (<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) I want to enter the password, I have to move or click on the mouse to type my password.

Alternatively I can use <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to access to password field.

I would like to be able to directly type my password like on any normal lockscreen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to test it in 22.04 this is absent. Most probably a bug that was fixed in later versions.

This is confirmed by older posts. Looking back, I have found this [Lock screen doesn't show login prompt from keyboard input](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=170863), linking to [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433054). (There is discussion [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251621) also.)

On Reddit too, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/sw6ey1/keyboard_inactive_to_awake_from_screen_lock/), with links that lead to bug reports [HERE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=450753) and [HERE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449857). All seem related.

Yours seems a milder form of the same problem.

I cannot personally test the workarounds or fixes discussed there (because I'm on Kubuntu 22.04) but at least one solution is described for Plasma 5.18 [HERE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449857#c47).

I repeat, I haven't tested this myself (if you try it make a backup of your file).

[Here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449857#c3) it says Plasma 5.24 has fixed this.

Comment: Thanks for all these details! Is there a way to update Plasma on Kubuntu?

Comment: The solution proposed at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449857#c47 works! Thanks!

Comment: You can wait if you like (Kubuntu 20.04 is supported for a long time) but considering your question about updating Plasma, you should not update it from PPA but eventually update from Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (meaning Plasma 5.24. But differences are trivial no matter what fans say). That is rather easy. Disable PPA or even use [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1016881/925128)  solution to downgrade if you already had backports PPA, Then follow something like [ this ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades/Kubuntu).