# Plasma application launchers other than the default one (and Krunner) don't show files and folders

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, 22.04, plasma

Some 3rd party applications menu/launchers do not show/search files and folders (are not meant to), but Krunner and Application Launcher (the default), as well as others, like Application Dashboard and Tiled Menu normally show files and folders, just like Krunner, for example:

[image]

After having used backports PPA in Kubuntu 22.04 for some time, some update brought this situation where the only ones that still have this feature are Krunner and Application Launcher. I was using Tiled Menu when this happened (I am used with opening my text files from the launcher).

I see that Application Dashboard and Application Menu (the old-style launcher) are affected too.

Could it be that the backports PPA brought with Plasma 5.25 some changes that are not yet supported by most launchers? How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a bug related to the (backports PPA( upgrade, and it was fixed by downgrading back to LTS with Plasma 5.4.24, using `ppa-purge`, as said in [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1016881/925128).

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

---

In order to get a solution without downgrading (given the same problem appeared on Fedora 36 where there was no point in downgrading etc) I have [posted](https://github.com/Zren/plasma-applet-tiledmenu/issues/135) a github issue for the author of Tiled Menu, who came up with [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/w0kd1o/comment/igjzvc6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) fix:

- Open `~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/com.github.zren.tiledmenu/contents/ui/SearchModel.qml`
- Delete `runnerModel.runners = filters`
- Delete `runners: [] // Empty = All runners`
- Restart plasmashell (logout)

I haven´t tried this fix for other launchers like Dashboard, because I use Tiled Menu.